# javascript truthy numbers

Tags: javascript, equality

Based on these rules:

**Falsy:**

- false
- 0 (zero)
- '' or "" (empty string)
- null
- undefinded
- NaN (e.g. the result of 1/0)

**Truthy:** Everything else

I fail to find the correct explanation as to why in following tests, only number 1 evaluates to "true"

```
0 == true ("false")
1 == true ("true")
2 == true ("false")
othernumber == true ("false")
```

Comment: The `==` operator has its own rules for how different types are converted, and specifically `x == true` does **not** mean, "is `x` truthy?".

Comment: `if (2 == true) console.log('nope');`
`if (2) console.log('yes')`

Comment: *"NaN (e.g. the result of 1/0)"* Actually, the result of 1/0 is Infinity. NaN is what you get when you try to convert something (a string, for instance) to a number and it cannot be converted: `Number("foo")` is `NaN`, for instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "truthy" and "falsy" rules only apply when the value itself is being used as the test, e.g.:

```
var str = "";
if (str) {
    // It's truthy
} else {
    // It's falsy
}
```

`==` has its own, different, set of rules for determining the loose equality of its operands, which are explained thoroughly in the spec's [Abstract Equality Comparison algorithm](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison):

> 1. If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then
>
>    - Return the result of performing Strict Equality Comparison x === y.
> 2. If x is null and y is undefined, return true.
> 3. If x is undefined and y is null, return true.
> 4. If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
> 5. If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
> 6. If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
> 7. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
> 8. If Type(x) is either String, Number, or Symbol and Type(y) is Object, return the result of the comparison x == ToPrimitive(y).
> 9. If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String, Number, or Symbol, return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.
> 10. Return false.

See the spec for the full details of the various abstract operations listed in there, although the names pretty much say what they do. (If you look at the spec, you'll see `!` prior to `ToNumber` in various places; I've removed it above. It's **not** the logical NOT operator, it's [a spec notation related to "abrupt completions."](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-returnifabrupt-shorthands))

Let's follow that through for your `2 == true` example:

1. The types aren't the same, so keep going
2. x isn't null, so keep going
3. x isn't undefined, so keep going
4. Type(x) is indeed Number, but Type(y) is not String, so keep going
5. Type(x) is not String, so keep going
6. Type(x) is not Boolean, so keep going
7. Type(y) is Boolean, so return the result of x == ToNumber(y)

   - ToNumber(true) is 1, and since 2 == 1 is false, the result is false

But notice that step 7 is different for your `1 == true` example:

7. Type(y) is Boolean, so return the result of x == ToNumber(y)

   - ToNumber(true) is 1, and since 1 == 1 is true, the result is true

Answer (score 2):

It's a very interesting reason, according to [this book](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch4.md), when you compare anything to a boolean like you are doing, for example in `x == y` it follows this pattern:

> If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
>
> If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).

Thus, when you compare `1 == true` it's actually doing `1 == ToNumber(true)` which then turns into `1 == 1`, but when you do `2 == true` it turns into `2 == 1` which is false fo course.

This and some other reasons given in the book suggest to not compare things to boolean values.

When you make a comparison to a boolean, it doesn't matter if the value itself is truthy or falsy, since it is never turned into a booleam, but the boolean is coerced into a type that can be compared to the other side of the `==` operator.

I hope you find this answer satisfactory.

Comment: Further context: the process is called coercion. In Javascript, values of different types are coerced into different type until they can be compared. The last step in that process is a number.

Comment: @Dylan - Not always a number.

Comment: I encourage you to go further into that book. It shows many dark things that happen in JS.

Answer (score 0):

using `==` is different from `if(something)`
This test will give you your expected results:

```
function truthyFalsyTest()
{
    if(0) 
    {
       console.log("true");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("false");
    }

    if(1) 
    {
       console.log("true");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("false");
    }

    if(2) 
    {
       console.log("true");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("false");
    }

    if(2222) 
    {
       console.log("true");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("false");
    }
}

truthyFalsyTest();
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript (==) is an equality operator operator where type conversion is done. The more strict (===) identity operator will not do type conversion.

For example, even though a number is not a boolean, you can use a numeric value where a boolean value is expected if using the (==) operator.

But, if you enforce the stricter (===) operator, you will see that '1 === true' will evaluate to false.

Answer (score 0):

> Based on these rules:
> The issue here is that `==` does NOT operate by these rules. Whether something is truthy or not and how it behaves during equality tests are two different things. For the record a more correct test for truthyness would be

```
if (value) 
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

or even shorter - a direct conversion `Boolean(value)` (and the implicit conversion `!!value`.

However, during an equality test, both sides of `==` will be transformed to the same base type and *then* the actual test occurs. [MDN has a list of rules for the conversion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Loose_equality_using) - straight from it a
`1 == true` uses a number and a boolean, therefore, the base type for both is *number*. The JavaScript environment will resolve this by calling `ToNumber(booleanValue)`, so here is what the equality test actually tests

```js
var convertedBooleanOperand = Number(true);

console.log("convertedBooleanOperand", convertedBooleanOperand);
```

In reality, `2 == true` is converted to `2 == 1` which is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

0 is false that doesn't mean othernumber will be true.. 
Simple example. If you use === in condition then you will see the false for all numbers.

```
(0 == true) // false
(1 == true) // true
```

It works fine. However, in below example, I have not used not operator (!) in the condition. So if condition is true it should print true else false.
Still it will give you reverse result.

```
if(0){console.log("true")}else{console.log("false")} // false
if(1){console.log("true")}else{console.log("false")} // true
if(15){console.log("true")}else{console.log("false")} // true
```

Now if you convert numbers to Boolean then it will give the result what you were thinking.

```
Boolean(0) == true // false
Boolean(1) == true // true
Boolean(2) == true // true
Boolean(othernumber) == true // true
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think the question was "how to make this code work" but rather "explain why it doesn't work as I expect it to".